# Install nou showing any install "type" options

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have an HP Pavilion laptop. Windows 10 Pro installed. I shrunk the partition with windows disk manager and left it as unallocated. I created a bootable USB using Rufus and Ubuntu 18.04.1. I boot the system with the USB drive and select install. I go through the language and keyboard screens and on the type screen is blank. no options. If I select ignore, I get a Libparted error.

> Could not stat device /dev/mapper/isw: untested metadata version 1.4.01 found on /dev/sda - no such file or directory

I have tried several things to no avail.

1. stopped fast boot in Windows.
2. launched `gparted` from the USB "live" session. I can see the free space and I created a new partition. I have tried Ubuntu 16.

Can anybody help me?